# Почему в React не добавили такой hook, и насколько хорошо он будет работать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Я не силён в react и в его тестировании. И чтобы получше разобраться с React, я решил написать собственный hook, решающую популярную проблему с ререндерингом.

***Проблема:*** к примеру, когда мы хотим привязать 2 дочерних компонента к одному родительскому состоянию (`state` из `useState`), то при изменении состояния происходит ререндер родительского компонента и как следствие всех дочерних компонентов. А в некоторых случаях хотелось бы чтобы происходил ререндер только тех компонентов, которые используют это состояние (`state`), исключая ререндер родительского компонента.

Для тех кому лень разбираться как работает мой hook (пара хуков), кратко опишу словами)

В родительском компоненте создаётся ref (из `useRef`). Дочерние компоненты подписываются на изменение этого ref и при изменении значения из ref происходит их принуждённый ререндер.

***Стандартный useState***

Синим подсвечены ререндеры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Мой hook***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Код хука***

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react"

const MagicContext = createContext(null)


export const useMagic = (value) => {
    const magicRef = useRef(value)
    const rerenderFunctions = new Map()
    const setMagicWithRerender = (value) => {
        magicRef.current = value
        const functions = Array.from(rerenderFunctions.values())
        functions.forEach((foo) => {
            foo()
        })
    }
    const unsubscribe = (elem) => {
        rerenderFunctions.delete(elem)
    }
    const subscribe = (elem, rerenderFoo) => {
        rerenderFunctions.set(elem, rerenderFoo)
    }
    const MagicProvider = (props) => {
        return <MagicContext.Provider value={{ magicRef, subscribe, unsubscribe, setMagicWithRerender }} {...props}>

        </MagicContext.Provider>

    }
    return { MagicProvider }
}
export const useMagicContext = () => {
    const { magicRef, subscribe, setMagicWithRerender, unsubscribe } = useContext(MagicContext)
    const uniqRef = useRef(null)
    const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        subscribe(uniqRef, () => {

            setRerender((p) => !p)
        })
        return () => unsubscribe(uniqRef)
    }, [unsubscribe, subscribe])


    const magic = useMemo(() => {

        return magicRef.current
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [rerender])



    return { setMagic: setMagicWithRerender, magic }
}
```

[Вы можете попробовать hook здесь](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-currying-fpw6lk)

Вопрос заключается в том, насколько правильно использовать такой функционал в react, насколько это правильно работает (и насколько он аналогичен стандартному связыванию через `useState`). Пожалуйста не оставляйте без ответа, хотя бы подскажите как я могу протестировать этот хук, или подскажите источники где я могу почитать про тестирование подобного.

И да, я понимаю что мой хук работает таким образом, что родительский компонент не имеет доступа к состоянию и не может его изменять!

Comment: Какой в этом смысл? И какова цель? Что бы 2 компонента имели одинаковое состояние? Есть в целом useContext, можно туда положить состояние и на него опираться без лишних хуков

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, естественно это сделано не для того чтобы просто связать 2 компонента, это всего лишь пример. Но вот очевидное отличие от useContext + useState, при изменении такого классического состояния будет происходить ререндер родительского компонента. А также при изменении состояния, из-за того что в контекст попадает новое значение, происходит ререндер всех дочерних компонентов, а не только тех которые используют это состояние.

Comment: Не будет происходить ререндер родителя,  если состояние не используется в компоненте. В вашем примере, состояние родителя явно передается в дочерние. Если обернуть контекстом, состояние положить родителю, а использовать в дочерних, то родитель рендерится не будет, хотя будет хранить состояние.

Comment: Так же для таких целей, можно использовать redux.

Comment: На счёт использования контекста, пожалуйста прикрепите код, если вы правильно меня поняли. Я имел ввиду, что мой хук ререндерит исключительно компоненты, которые используют хук useMagicContext (и соответственно их дочерние). Когда я проверял у себя useState+useContext у меня devtool подсвечивал ререндер родительского компонента. На счёт redux, я написал, что хочу разобраться как именно работает react, и его популярные библиотеки. Мне больше хотелось бы, чтобы не вслепую использовать redux, а понять как он работает изнутри

Comment: Да, рендер происходит у родителя... Ладно, вопрос основной - какой функционал реализует ваш хук? Я пока не понял, как полезно его можно применить. Из увиденного - это псевдо контекст или даже стейт(который просто можно зацепить другому элементу). Как мне кажется, вы сделали контекст с полуредаксом(обновить компонент в любом месте по изменению данных)

Comment: @SwaD На счёт функционала моего хука. Основной его смысл заключается по сути создание того же функционала ```useState + useContext```, но с предотвращении нежелательных ререндерингов (обновлять только те элементы которые используют этот контекст). Я специально по-быстрому сделал хук (хочу использовать в дальнейшем в более сложных кастомных хуках, похожий функционал). И я хотел узнать как я могу затестить его, насколько правильно так делать, нет ли каких-нибудь багов. Где можно применить? Можно использовать его к примеру для корзины в интернет-магазине

Comment: Опять же, это тот же state+context, но без ререндера компонентов которым информация о state не нужна